# Mongo db group within a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I have a User schema and a Order schema like below:
User -

```
{
    "_id" : user1,
    "fullName" : "test",
    "phone" : "8494948432",
    "phoneCode" : "+91",
}
```

Orders -

```
/* 1 */
{
    "orderId" : "ODR0000000486",
    "status" : "delivered",  //status can be delivered, undelivered, etc
    "user": user1 //refering user
}
/* 2 */
{
    "orderId" : "ODR0000000487",
    "status" : "undelivered",  
    "user": user1 
}
```

Now i want to get user's delivered order count, undelivered count, a object like this

```
{
    "_id": user1,
    "fullName" : "test",
    "phone" : "8494948432",
    "phoneCode" : "+91",
    "delivered": 1,
    "undelivered": 1
}
```

I have tried with aggregate on users using two different look up to orders, but it doesn't look good and is not efficient when there are mutiple order data to be calculated.
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([

```
{
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "orders",
      "let": {
        "userId": "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$status",
                    "delivered"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$user",
                    "$$userId"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "delivered"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "orders",
      "let": {
        "userId": "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$status",
                    "undelivered"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$user",
                    "$$userId"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "undelivered"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "fullName": 1,
      "phone": 1,
      "phoneCode": 1,
      "delivered": {
        "$size": "$delivered"
      },
      "undelivered": {
        "$size": "$undelivered"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Is there any way I can get this data by a single look-up and other mongo db options/functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

[Sample live demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_YOAF2PnS_Q)

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "orders",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "user",
      as: "orders"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$orders"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "userId": "$_id"
      },
      "data": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      },
      "delivered": {
        "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$orders.status", "delivered"]}, 1, 0 ] }
      },
      "undelivered": {
        "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$orders.status", "undelivered"]}, 1, 0 ] }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": "$_id.userId",
      "fullName": "$data.fullName",
      "phone": "$data.phone",
      "phoneCode": "$data.phoneCode",
      "delivered": "$delivered",
      "undelivered": "$undelivered"
    }
  }
])
```